# Mysql complicated query with join and count to do same work as subquery and to use it in zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, join, left-join, zend-db

I have a rather complicated query that I want to put into use with Zend Framework. In order to do this I needed to convert query from subqueries to joins.

This is the deal: I have 3 tables that need to be connected in order to form proper info. This can be accomplished using this query:

```
SELECT 
 ol.orders_id, 
 ol.photos_to_add, 
 ol.locations_id, 
 l.name, 
 (select 
   count(*) 
  from 
   photos as p 
  where 
   p.location_id = ol.locations_id and p.per_order = ol.orders_id) 
  as added 
FROM `order_has_locations` AS ol, 
 `locations` AS l 
WHERE ol.orders_id = 1 and l.id = ol.locations_id
```

I try to convert it to joins:

```
SELECT ol.orders_id, ol.locations_id, ol.photos_to_add, l.name, count(p.id) AS added
FROM order_has_locations as ol
INNER JOIN locations as l on l.id = ol.locations_id
left outer join photos as p on p.per_order = ol.orders_id
where p.location_id = ol.locations_id and ol.orders_id = 1
```

but this way the info about 0 photos is missing.

I tried many different approaches to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

That is because of p.location_id = ol.locations_id, move this condition from where to join clause, it should work. As currently it in where clause it is applied after join has evaluated, hence for 0 photos this condition turns out to be p.location_id = null which is false and hence rows are filtered out.

```
SELECT ol.orders_id, ol.locations_id, ol.photos_to_add, l.name, count(p.id) AS added
  FROM order_has_locations as ol
 INNER JOIN locations as l on l.id = ol.locations_id
  LEFT outer join photos as p on p.per_order = ol.orders_id 
   AND p.location_id = ol.locations_id 
 WHERE ol.orders_id = 1
 GROUP BY ol.orders_id, ol.locations_id, ol.photos_to_add, l.name
```

Comment: Well, I hoped that this would work, but unfortunately it doesn't - the return values are the same as for my original join-query.

Comment: Can you give some example? input data and expected output data

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY for aggregate functions. And left join is an outer join by definition, you needn't specify that.

```
SELECT ol.orders_id, ol.locations_id, ol.photos_to_add, l.name, count(p.id) AS added
FROM order_has_locations as ol
INNER JOIN locations as l on l.id = ol.locations_id
LEFT JOIN photos as p on p.per_order = ol.orders_id
where p.location_id = ol.locations_id and ol.orders_id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```